# Is statement “No rings are bangles” equivalent to “No bangles are ring” in syllogism?

Tags: logic

I was solving one question related to Syllogism. But I am not understanding the answer.

Is statement "No rings are bangles" equivalent to "No bangles are rings" in syllogism?

**Question:**

```
Statements :
No rings are bangles.
All gold are rings.

Conclusions :
I. No bangles are gold.
II. Some rings are gold.
```

a) Only conclusion I follows
b) Both conclusions I and II follow
c) Only conclusion II follows
d) Neither conclusion I nor conclusion II follows
e) None of these

Answer: c

As per my opinion answer should be **b**. Because if "No rings are bangles", to make 1st conclusion false there should be a case exists where at least one Bangle which is a Gold. If B=G exists then, as per statement all golds are rings. It means B=G=R. Which is contradicting the given statement.

Comment: Yes. No A are B means that there is no object that is both A and B and “and” is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

Why I is a valid conclusion ? Assume not: there is something that is both Bangle and Gold. Thus, by 2nd premise, it is also Bangle and Ring, contradicting 1st premise.